# JQM: Why does the same jQuery selector return a different number of elements depending on the current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

When first opening (or refreshing) my app, where the Home page is current, and then executing the following command from the console:

```
$("a.ui-collapsible-heading-toggle").length
```

the return value is 1. There are 4 collapsible widgets in total, but only 1 on the Home page. If I then click the Documentation tab and execute the same command, it returns the correct number, 4 - there are 3 widgets on this page. If I then click the Home page tab (or any other tab) the correct result of 4 is displayed.

I am using JQM version 1.4.5 and jQuery 2.1.3.

Can anyone explain this inconsistent behavior?

Comment: On click of the __Documentation__, DOM is updated..

Comment: Is there a way to update the DOM without clicking on a tab?

Comment: To whomever it has who downvoted this question, please explain your reasons.

Comment: After closer inspection, Rayon, I found that clicking on any other tab not containing any collapsibles, also show a length of 1.

Comment: Collapsibles are created when page is visited for the first time. On Home you have one, so you get one. When you navigate to next page with 3 collapsibles, you get 4, because both pages are in DOM.

Comment: You need to do this: `var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "getActivePage" )` and then search inside active page `$( ".foo", activePage )` this will return elements in active page only, not all items in DOM.

Comment: Thanks, Omar. This makes sense. Is there a seamless way to load all collapsible widgets on page load? I need to have all of them available when users change the language drop-down from the home page.

Comment: On all pages, visited or not? If yes, you have to add all markup statically and inform jQM that these items are already enhanced. Check documentation/API for pre-enhanced elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omar pointed me in the right direction. Collapsible widgets are only loaded when a JQM page is loaded. The solution is to data-prefetch pages as indicated in this [JQM document](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html). Notice that the data-prefeth attribute can be applied to both single-page and multiple-page options.

Since only two of the four pages of my app. contained collapsible widgets, I only needed to specify "data-prefetch" on links to these pages.

On the home page, the navbar links that specified data-prefetch are a follows:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" data-prefetch class="ui-btn ui-state-persist ui-icon-home" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#demo" class="ui-btn ui-icon-info" data-icon="info">Examples</a></li>
        <li><a href="#documentation" data-prefetch class="ui-btn ui-icon-info" data-icon="info">Documentation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="ui-btn ui-icon-mail" data-icon="mail">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the data=prefetch attribute on both the #home and #docmentation links.

The combination of these data-prefetch attributes resulted in the correct number of selected elements, 4.